# Confused about Nesterov momentum gradient descent algorithm

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I've found a variety of variations of writing Nesterov but I cannot understand why they cannot simply be expanded into a one liner.

Here is one I found that can just be re-arranged, can someone explain why I am wrong?

$\theta_t = y_t - \gamma \nabla f(y_t) \\
y_{t+1} = \theta_t + \rho (\theta_t - \theta_{t-1})$

Plug first equation into second,

$y_{t+1} = y_t - \gamma \nabla f(y_t) + \rho (\theta_t - \theta_{t-1})$

Let $\Delta y_t = y_{t+1} - y_{t}$ then it simply becomes

$$\Delta y_t = - \gamma \nabla f(y_t) + \rho (y_t - \gamma \nabla f(y_t) - y_{t-1} + \gamma \nabla f(y_{t-1}) \\
 = - \gamma \nabla f(y_t) + \rho (\Delta y_{t-1}  + \gamma (\nabla f(y_{t-1}) - \nabla f(y_{t})) $$

so what am I doing wrong?

In fact I've found a similar form in a paper: *Ning  Qian.   On  the  momentum  term  in  gradient  descentlearning  algorithms.Neural  Networks,  12(1):145  –  151,1999.*

where gradient descent with momentum is defined as

$$\Delta \theta_t = - \gamma \nabla f(\theta) + \rho \Delta \theta_{t-1} $$ (I'm also not sure why it's $f(\theta)$ and not $f(\theta_t)$)

Comment: Why do you think it’s wrong to write it in one line?

Comment: What about the update for the momentum term in the one-liner?